# sizeof char pointer and pointer to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Consider this:

```
    char *word;
    char **sentence;
```

Why does `sizeof(*word)` return 1, and why does `sizeof(*sentence)` return 8?

Thanks.

Comment: Because `sizeof (char)` is `1`, and `sizeof(char*)` is 8 ?

Comment: When you use `*` in an expression it's dereferencing it, it's not part of the variable's name. At least I think that's what you're confused about, the question isn't very clear.

Comment: Mister_L, What did you expect `sizeof(*word)` to return?

Comment: Your title refers to `sizeof(char*)` and `sizeof(char**)`, but `*word` has type `char` and `sizeof(char)` is 1.  That is `*word` is not a char pointer - it is a `char`.  The `*` in the expression `*word` is the _dereference operator_, whereas in the _declaration_ `char* word;`, it is part of the type name. (which I why it is probably better to place it adjacent to the base type-name rather than the variable name - it is not part of the variable name, and is not an operator in that context).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pointer declared on the form `type *name`, then `sizeof(*name)` is equivalent to `sizeof(type)`. If you want the size of the actual pointer, then omit the asterisk and use `sizeof(name)`.

Answer (score 1):

`word` is of type `char*`, which has an implementation-defined size (apparently 8 on your system).

`*word` is of type `char`, which by definition has a size of 1 byte.

`sentence` is of type `char**`, pointer to pointer to `char`.

`*sentence` is of type `char*`, which has the same implementation-defined size as `word`.

`**sentence` is of type `char`.

The expression `sizeof expr` (or `sizeof (expr)` is equivalent to `sizeof (TYPE)`, where `TYPE` is the type of `expr`. `expr` is not evaluated when it's the operand of `sizeof` (unless it's of variable length array type).

Answer (score 0):

The types of the expressions are different :

- The type of expression ***word** is char , the size of char is 1
- The type of expression ***sentence** is *char, the size of *char is 8

Answer (score -1):

Because the size of any pointer to any type is the size of a word which is machine or
compiler dependent and remain same for all data type pointer, in your case, it
is 8 byte. Now the size of a character is 1 byte.
`sizeof(*word)` gives the size of the byte which is pointed by word pointer that is a
character so it gives 1 byte.

now `**sentence` is a pointer of the pointer(double pointer) that means when you use
`sizeof(*sentence)` it actually gives you the size of a pointer which is pointed by
`**character` pointer that is 1 word so it gives 8 bytes.

Pointer is like a thread(link) to a box(memory address which is in byte) in which some
item(value) is placed. Same as "to store big items you need a bigger box (size varies by
data type)" but thread(link) did not need to depend on item or box size they remain same
to point any box.

But while using a double pointer you are actually using a thread to a box which contains
another thread to actual box in which value is placed.

so you get the size of the first pointer which contains a link to the actual data type value.

if you use `sizeof(**sentence)` you get output 1.

Comment: The phrase "double pointer" is ambiguous; it can refer to a pointer to a pointer or to `double*`. There is no guarantee that all object pointer types have the same size, or that that size is a "word" (C doesn't define what a "word" is).

Comment: Pointers to functions are often different size than pointers to objects.  Pointers to various object type may different in size - although this is not commonly seen. "size of any pointer ... is the size of a word" is well off the mark.  Word size and pointer  size are not specified to be the same.

Comment: @chux my bad, I didn't know about pointers to functions at that time. I studied it now, thanks :).